# Issue with executeUpdate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql-10

I am facing issue with executeUpdate in Hibernate.
The query that is being fired through hibernate is like

```
Update table set column1='abc',column2=:time,servertime=:servertime where service IN :arrservice
```

There are for suppose 4 services to be updated 
'abcd','pqrs,'xyz','def'

Sometimes it updates all,sometimes some out of all services and sometimes no service is updated.

I neither get any exception nor any error.
Where I check same query using select with those services,I get the records for it but at the same time update doesn't work for them.

```
String queryStm="Update table set column1='abc',column2=:time,servertime=:servertime where service IN :arrservice"
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryStm);
            query.setParameter("arrservice", arrService);
            query.setParameter("time", time);
            query.setParameter("servertime", new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));

LOG.debug("No updated" + query.executeUpdate());
```

If there are for suppose 4 services to be updated,the above log sometimes gives 4,3,2 and 0 as well.

I am not sure what's wrong here.Why its not updating all 4 always.
I am using Postgres 10 on server and following is the dependency that I have included in pom:-

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Any help would be very much appreciable.

Comment: Do any other queries work from your implementation?

Comment: Perhaps, I saw somewhere issue like that, and root of that was in Date. If you can, try to change your Date column, to boolean, or String, for example, just to check that problem doesn't connect with that. It's just a one idea

Comment: Maybe you should post the exact query. As of now, you set 3 parameter while only 2 are available

Comment: I have updated my post,its having 3 columns as last with server time

Comment: @Dred According to me it won't be an issue with date column because it doesn't happen in all cases sometimes it updates as well.

Comment: @J_D Yes it does work and even it does work for same query also.As for example today it had records to be updated as 4 and query.executeUpdate returned 2.

Comment: @Divya it can be depended by current Date, for example, if you update in 1 hour or in 1 day, or in 1 minute. It depends on the Timestamp in your table. Anyway, You don't lose anything besides your time. But, while you haven't any solution, why shouldn't try? ;)

Comment: Did you try the current version of the driver? The JDBC version 9.1 is completely outdated (and won't work with Postgres 10 properly). The current version is of the driver is 42.2.5

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes I tried different version 42.2.5 but still it did not work.Its still not updating.